# Android AdView not visible - but clickable

Tags: java, android, admob

I have created an Android app with the new ads sdk, but it is invisible. I got it working in a previous app, it works good there. Now, in my new app, I have done the same. But:

The AdView is not visible, but clickable. If you go back to your home screen (just minimize, dont stop!), and re-open it, the ad will be shown.

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<org.andengine.opengl.view.RenderSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/SurfaceViewId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adViewId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adUnitId="XXX"
    ads:adSize="BANNER" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adViewId);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
}
```

**EDIT:** After 60 sec., the view becomes visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have told you RenderSurfaceView to matchParent forits height. THis means that it will consume all of the space of its parent leaving none for the AdView.

Try this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<org.andengine.opengl.view.RenderSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/SurfaceViewId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adViewId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="XXX"
    ads:adSize="BANNER" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This uses layout_weight with LinearLayout to have your RenderSurfaceView expand to fill all unused vertical space.

Comment: Basically this works. In my case, the RenderSurfaceView's width got smaller, but I am sure you could fix this.

Taken from another question here, I have found this solution: Call any method that updates the ad.

This works good for me:

`adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);`

But actually, your solution is working.

Comment: You are better off not forcing a touch of the UI. Configure it correctly to begin with. The code above should have have affected the width of your RenderView in any way, that smells of something else wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot implementing these important methods

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    this.adView.pause();
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    this.adView.resume();
}
```

Comment: No, this is not the problem. Also explicitly calling those methods (onResume() in this case) does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is any foreground set to your parent layout in which you are loading adview. In my case there was a foreground color set and on fast scrolling of recyclerview, foreground color was being set over AdView.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_strip_ad"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:foreground="?attr/window_background_attr" //on commenting this line issue resolved.
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adViewId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="XXX"
        ads:adSize="BANNER" />

</LinearLayout>
```